# C++11-related compilation error with g++ 4.6 and boost::unordered_map

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, stl, c++11

I have some piece of C++ code that fails with a compilation error unless it is run in C++11 mode, but I can't figure out why that would be the case as the code does not (explicitly) use C++11 features:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

struct SomeStruct {
  boost::unordered_map<int, int> intMap;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  std::vector<SomeStruct> vals;

  vals.resize(100);
}
```

When compiling this on an Ubuntu 12.04 64bit machine with gcc 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 and boost 1.48:

```
g++ test.cpp
```

then I get this compilation error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/vector:61:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h: In function 'typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<(! std::__is_scalar<_Tp>::__value), void>::__type std::__fill_a(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator = SomeStruct*, _Tp = SomeStruct, typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<(! std::__is_scalar<_Tp>::__value), void>::__type = void]':
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:722:7:   instantiated from 'void std::fill(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator = SomeStruct*, _Tp = SomeStruct]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/vector.tcc:397:5:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_fill_insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const value_type&) [with _Tp = SomeStruct, _Alloc = std::allocator<SomeStruct>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<SomeStruct*, std::vector<SomeStruct> >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer = SomeStruct*, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = SomeStruct]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:944:9:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const value_type&) [with _Tp = SomeStruct, _Alloc = std::allocator<SomeStruct>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<SomeStruct*, std::vector<SomeStruct> >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer = SomeStruct*, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = SomeStruct]'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:632:4:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::resize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type) [with _Tp = SomeStruct, _Alloc = std::allocator<SomeStruct>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = SomeStruct]'
test.cpp:12:18:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:676:2: error: no match for 'operator=' in '* __first = __value'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:676:2: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:5:8: note: SomeStruct& SomeStruct::operator=(SomeStruct&)
test.cpp:5:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const SomeStruct' to 'SomeStruct&'
```

This compiles fine when enabling C++11 support in gcc:

```
g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp
```

Could somebody explain why this only works in C++11 mode ?

**Edit:**

Steps to reproduce using Vagrant:

```
vagrant init precise64
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libboost1.48-all-dev
echo "#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

struct SomeStruct {
  boost::unordered_map<int, int> intMap;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  std::vector<SomeStruct> vals;

  vals.resize(100);
}" > test.cpp
g++ test.cpp
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on gcc 4.6.3 or 4.8, ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and boost 1.46.

Comment: No errors under MinGW using gcc 4.7.0 and boost 1.49, compiling with `-std=c++03`

Comment: Sorry, this was with boost 1.48 not 1.46. Steps to reproduce using Vagrant:
`vagrant init precise64;
vagrant up;
vagrant ssh;
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libboost1.48-all-dev;
echo "#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

struct SomeStruct {
  boost::unordered_map<int, int> intMap;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  std::vector<SomeStruct> vals;

  vals.resize(100);
}" > test.cpp;
g++ test.cpp`

Comment: Try to comment out the `std::vector::resize` line.

Comment: @bamboon The code compiles fine with the resize line commented out.

Comment: Perhaps it's clear to everyone that adding `SomeStruct &operator= (const SomeStruct &x) { intMap = x.intMap; return *this; }` solves or works around the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The copy-assignment operator of `boost::unordered_map` is declared as:

```
unordered_map& operator=(unordered_map &t)
```

which in turn causes (C++98 12.8 [#10]) the implicit copy-assignment operator of `SomeStruct` to be declared as:

```
SomeStruct &operator= (SomeStruct &);
```

Adding an explicit copy-assignment operator

```
SomeStruct &operator= (const SomeStruct &x) { intMap = x.intMap; return *this; }
```

solves the issue, and it works by invoking a different overload of `unordered_map::operator=`.

This issue is fixed in Boost 1.52. which declares the operator as:

```
unordered_map& operator=(unordered_map const& x);
```

Comment: will your explicit copy-assignment compile at all? intMap = x.intMap should fail - x.intMap is const here, so no appropriate overload of copy-assignment for unordered map will be found.

Comment: @Basilevs, there exists another overload of `operator=` - `unordered_map& operator=(const ::boost::rv< unordered_map >& x)`, I mentioned it above.

Comment: @chill: Thanks, adding the copy-assignment operator worked like a charm!